# Equality of polyhedra

Tags: linear-programming, computational-geometry, polyhedra

Is a minimal representation for a polyhedron unique? And if so can we use this to prove that two polyhedra are equal (or maybe the same is a better definition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you call "minimal representation".

It exists a canonical representation of any polyhedron, called polygonal canonical schemata (see [1]) which is unique. This representation can be used to test if two polyhedra are "equal", more precisely homeomorphic, i.e. they have the same topology.

[1] Gert Vegter , Chee K. Yap, Computational complexity of combinatorial surfaces, Proceedings of the sixth annual symposium on Computational geometry, p.102-111, June 07-09, 1990, Berkley, California, USA

Comment: That's a good answer. To farther extend my question what happens if I have an algebraic representation of a polyhedron i.e. $P=\{x\in R^n \mid Ax\leq b\}$